Why the compiler tries to call A(int) to construct instead of A(int, int) when calling std::vector<A>::emplace_back(int, int) in C++17?
#include<vector>
struct A{};
int main() {
    std::vector<A>a;
    a.emplace_back(0, 0);
}

Compiling this code with -std=c++17, the error below is shown:
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/new_allocator.h:187:11: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]
  187 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/new_allocator.h:187:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(int)’
a.cpp:2:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr A::A()’
    2 | struct A{};
      |        ^

The compiler tried to call A::A(int).
However, after I provided A(int) for A, the compilers tried to call A::A(int, int):
/usr/include/c++/13/bits/new_allocator.h:187:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(int, int)’
  187 |         { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp:3:5: note: candidate: ‘A::A(int)’
    3 |     A(int x) {}
      |     ^

Why did the compiler behave like that?


error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]

This means:

I could interpret the , as an operator, but that's illegal in this context, so I won't unless you pass -fpermissive.

You can get a similar error message from this:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x(1,2);
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

This is not legal C++, but compiles and prints 2 with -fpermissive.
In other words, your code wouldn't actually call a single-argument constructor unless you used -fpermissive, GCC just has a weird error message.

You have too many initializers to initialize an A. As defined, an A takes exactly zero initializers, but you provide two. The proper way to emplace an A into your vector<A> is:
a.emplace_back(); // zero initializers

... but if what you want is just two default initialized As, then make it:
std::vector<A> a(2);

... or if using an initializer list is preferable for some reason:
std::vector<A> a{{},{}}; // a will contain two `A`s


Sorry, I may not have explained it clearly. I wonder why does the compiler show the error, like it tried to call A::A(int) instead of A::A(int, int). I know what mistake this code contains ans how to fix it.

@nalemy Your question is clear enough. I was tired when I read the question and I didn't "see" that part of it.
